# sourceTree&Git: remote Repository not found

Tags: git, sourcetree

I have sourceTree and git set up on my machine to work on a project with other people. When I tried to push my first changes through sourceTree, I got **remote: Repository not found**

The link sourceTree is pushing to is in the following format:
[https://*myGitUserName*@github.com/*ourOrganisation*/*ourProject*.git](https://_myGitUserName_@github.com/_ourOrganisation_/_ourProject_.git)

Does anyone know why it is saying that this repository is not found?

Could it be that I need some special rights to 'Push To Origin' (i.e myGitUserName is not allowed to push, hence no repository)? - If yes, how do I check/request these?

Thank you!

Comment: Visit the repository on GitHub with your browser, and then copy the URL from the green “Clone or download” button on the right. This will avoid any spelling errors. Permission problems are usually explained as permission problems, so “repository not found” does not appear to be a permission problem.

Comment: If I do that I will push to the master branch (not on my own)? (https://github.com/ourOrganisation/ourProject.git)

Comment: The branch you push to is independent of the remote configuration. You need to configure the remote properly first. And then you can decide which branch you push to by using e.g. `git push origin branchname`

Comment: I am very new to git, so sorry if I am doing something stupid: In source tree I created a new branch and am trying to push to that branch (and got the problem from my question). Now, still in sourceTree, I copy the URL from the green button and custom push to that (master) repository - doing so I get **remote: Repository not found** ....

Comment: Did you start by cloning this project through source tree, or did you init a new repository on your local drive?

Comment: I cloned it. (It was a while back now, but I dont remember using init)

Comment: Try pulling from the remote repository. If you don't see the same error then most probably it is a permission issue.

Comment: You should see everything in `git remote show origin`. This is also something you can post...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My team made me an admin in the git group and then pushing worked just fine with the previous settings.